# File names are converted to lowercase in source map generated by sass

Tags: sass

Say my Main.scss file has this:

```
@import "TestFile";
```

Then I run:

```
sass --source-map Main.scss Main.css
```

Then the generated source map will have:

```
sources: ["main.scss","testfile.scss"]
```

This will cause file not found in case-sensitive web server, http://xxx.xxx.xxx/testfile.scss will not get the content from http://xxx.xxx.xxx/TestFile.scss
May I know if this is by design? And if there is any walkaround to make the generated source list match the original file name case?

Thanks!